# AsyncTask generating RuntimeException

Tags: java, android, sql, android-asynctask

I have written an AsyncTask extended class which reads data from internet. Although the code is working fine in emulator (GB) i-e; it is returning data from internet but when I run the code on my phone (JB), it doesn't return anything. Moreover the code is creating following exceptions in logcat of emualtor. Here is the code:

```
new userCred().execute(userCredentials);

public class userCred extends AsyncTask<String[], String, String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String[]... arg0) {

        ......

        startActivity(intent);

        return null; // because I am not returning anythign
    }

}
```

LOGCAT:

```
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at com.umer.androiduetproject.LoginAccount.sendCredentialsForCheckingOnline(LoginAccount.java:71)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at com.umer.androiduetproject.LoginAccount$userCred.doInBackground(LoginAccount.java:124)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at com.umer.androiduetproject.LoginAccount$userCred.doInBackground(LoginAccount.java:1)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-15 21:49:56.768: W/System.err(1542):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542):     at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542):     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542):     at com.umer.androiduetproject.LoginAccount.sendCredentialsForCheckingOnline(LoginAccount.java:71)
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542):     at com.umer.androiduetproject.LoginAccount$userCred.doInBackground(LoginAccount.java:124)
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542):     at com.umer.androiduetproject.LoginAccount$userCred.doInBackground(LoginAccount.java:1)
07-15 21:50:24.169: W/System.err(1542):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-15 21:50:24.179: W/System.err(1542):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-15 21:50:24.179: W/System.err(1542):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-15 21:50:24.179: W/System.err(1542):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 07-15 21:50:24.179: W/System.err(1542):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 07-15 21:50:24.179: W/System.err(1542):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

JB LOGCAT:

```
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b50afe10 that was originally bound here
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b50afe10 that was originally bound here
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
 07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):    at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/ActivityThread(1466):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466): null
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@b50afe10 that was originally bound here
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
```

07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
07-15 18:51:36.378: E/StrictMode(1466):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do restricted things on a background thread. JellyBean has gotten much more strict with enforcing this rule, and GingerBread wasn't. Which is why there was not issue on your emulator but it broke on your device. Move startActivity(intent) and any other UI interactive code to onPostExecute instead, or use a Handler to post messages to the main thread from your AsyncTask. You really only just want to do background and potentially blocking operations in an AsyncTask. Hope this helps

EDIT: Turns out you were trying to show a Toast in your doInBackground(). This also is not allowed, as you're trying to interact with Views that are meant to be touched on the main thread. Remove that toast, and use Log instead or use a Handler instance to show it.

Comment: ok so now what I did, I am reading internet data in doBackground() and start new Activity in onPostExecute(). But still I am getting the above exceptions and now the new activity is not starting!

Comment: You are trying to show a Toast in your doInBackground, please see my edited answer

Comment: yep I removed that. Please ignore UI elements in doInBackground

Comment: Has it solved your problem? The stacktrace you posted shows that the Toast was in fact your problem

Comment: Still it is not running on my JB phone

Comment: this is the old stack trace after your answer, I removed all the UI components from doInBackground, but still my phone is not starting the new activity

Comment: new stacktrace has no errors, the whole point of the question is new activity is opening on emulator but it is not opening on JB phone

Comment: If something is not behaving correctly, more than likely there's info/hints/explicit reasoning in the stackTrace. Programs are deterministic, they do what you instruct them to. So, without more detail..I don't see how anyone can really help you.

Comment: @UmerFarooq As pointed out by Jade Byfield, you are not allowed to touch UI from other threads. This has been enforced by the strict policy on the newer versions of Android. And this is why it doesnt run on your JB phone.

Comment: I am posting JB stacktrace